# Manual Transitions in jQuery Cycle plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I want to add a custom data attribute to each slide and, on the before event, grab the attribute's value and manually set the Cycle plugin's transition to the next slide.  Can this be accomplished using the jQuery Cycle plugin?